# How would I make a custom environment to accomplish the following

Tags: theorems, alignment

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newenvironment*{exercise}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{exercise}{1.10.}
Hello World\\
Hello world\\

Hello World
\end{exercise}

\end{document}
```

How would I format this so that all instances of Hello World are aligned. That is that all the H's would be aligned. I am trying to replicate the format found in many mathematics textbooks which is why I am experimenting with theorem environments.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). Do you mean `\par\noindent`? Perhaps you should include an image of exactly what you are trying to accomplish a it is not clear, at least to me.

Comment: No. Essentially I want the 1.10 to appear to the left of everything placed inside of the environment with the lines of text all aligned.

Comment: One per line? What is 1.10. supposed to be, exactly?

Comment: 1.10 is the exercise number.